# Given A, B, G, H prove the I know x s.t. $A=xG$ and $B=xH$

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Given A, B, G, H .How would I prove that I know x such that
$A=xG$ and $B=xH$

Comment: See Chaum–Pedersen, or Fujisaki–Okamoto if the group has composite order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard $\Sigma$-protocol for proving knowledge of a witness showing that $(G,H,A,B)$ is a DDH-tuple, assuming a group of prime order $p$:

- The prover picks a random exponent $r \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and sends $(R,S) = (rG, rH)$.
- The verifier sends a random challenge $e$ from $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
- The prover computes and send $d = e\cdot x + r$.
- The verifier accepts the proof if and only if $eA+R = dG$ and $eB+S=dH$.

Since you seem to ask these questions for the purpose of learning, I'd suggest that you try to prove yourself the security of this protocol (that is, soundness, and honest-verifier zero-knowledge). You can take inspiration from the security analysis I gave for a similar protocol in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70877/is-a-hash-a-zero-knowledge-proof/70883#70883), that deals with the Schnorr protocol (about which you asked in [another question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/given-p-xg-prove-in-zero-knowledge-that-i-know-sqrtx)).

Comment: Although it's taken me a long time to do (on and off), I have nearly completed this exercise without looking at the other links. Thank you for the inspiration