# Given $P=xG$, prove in zero knowledge that I know $sqrt(x)$

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Assuming that x has a sqrt.

Given $P=xG$ is it possible to prove that I know the $sqrt(x)$ in zero knowledge?

Comment: Is the group of prime order? If so it's trivial to compute the square root and it would suffice to prove knowledge of $x$.

Comment: @SEJPM Yep, it's a group of prime order. If I've given the verifier P, how would I convince him that I know the sqrt(x) without sending it to him? After I computer it, what would I do?

Comment: Hi, WeCanBeFriends, and welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. I notice that you've been posting several questions today that look like homework assignments. Please note that, while asking questions *arising* from homework is not forbidden here, this site is not a do-my-homework service, and questions consisting of just a problem statement with no context [are likely to get closed](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Got it. They are not homework problems, just questions that I find interesting, and have run into dead-ends with.

Comment: @SEJPM: yes, it's trivial to compute square-roots of quadratic residues, however not all group members are quadratic residues.  You would also need to prove that the $x$ you know is one...

Comment: I see. In that case, I'd suggest editing your questions to explain the context in which you ran into those problems. Not only does that make them seem less "homework-like", but it will also help people answer them in a way that will actually be useful to you (e.g. by noting potential further issues to consider and suggesting alternative solutions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer simply extends the comment by SEJPM.

Since the group has prime order (as you said in the comment), and since you assume that it is known that $x$ has a square root, you can simply prove knowledge of $x$ such that $xG = P$, using the standard Schnorr protocol for demonstrating knowledge of a discrete logarithm (see e.g. the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge), or my description [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70877/is-a-hash-a-zero-knowledge-proof/70883#70883) for a simplified security analysis of this protocol).

Now, since knowing $x$ is equivalent to knowing $\sqrt{x}$ in a group of prime order (each can be computed from the other in polynomial time), convincing the verifier that you know $x$ does also convince him that you know $\sqrt{x}$. Since the proof leaks nothing about $x$, it leaks nothing about $\sqrt{x}$.